# 'Unknown archive file size' when installing garamondx

Tags: miktex, installing-fonts, garamondx

I am trying to install `garamondx` in MiKTeX, Windows 10 x64. I have ran the MiKTeX updater and synchronized the package database too. The error I get is

> Unknown archive file size.

I know I can install it manually in my TeXMF tree, but it would still be good to get rid of this error.

Comment: My experience: Wait a couple of days and re-try and/or choose another server.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: @egreg Nope, it still gives the same error.

Comment: Any news? Does it gives still the same error or solved with time/waiting?

Comment: @Bobyandbob It still gives the same error